# Is it possible to create mysql accounts for 'user' and have that account access a different page of the website?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm creating a website where me "as an admin" can create other accounts for "users".

- When I login as an admin it will be directed to a page like "superuser.php" where I can create an account for "users" in the GUI of the website.
- When the created "user" account is logged in it will be directed to a page like "user.php" with a different privilege.

Thank you so much

Comment: The short answer is yes, but it's normally done with coding.